# How to get importing progress and error log when importing data from kafka to elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, apache-kafka-connect

**Background**:

I'm trying to import data from kafka to elasticsearch, and there are 2 kinds of clients. One is web client, another one is agent client.

Web client will handle csv file when user upload, web client reads every 10,000 rows from csv file and send the data message with the csv total lines count to Producer. Producer send the message to kafka, then consumer pulls the message, and imports data into elasticsearch. At the same time consumer uses the data messages length and csv total count to  update task progress, also updates error logs if it has. At last our web client would know the errors and importing progress.

Agent client watch log file changes, once the new log is coming, it would send message to producer, the same as web client, but it does not care about progress. As the logs is always growing like nginx logs.

**Framework**:

Here is the framework that I used:
[image]

The producer and consumer are our python programs that used [kafka-python](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python).

**Problems**:

1. Sometimes the consumer crashed, it would been auto restart and
   reimported the same data again.
2. Sometime client send too many
   messages, Producer might miss some, as the http request has
   limitation I guess.

**Question:**

Is there any better framework to do those thing? like using kafka-connect-elasticsearch , spark streaming ?

Comment: Did you look to Logstash? What kind of work producers & consumers need to perform - only data pushing, or some custom logic as well? What format is used for data? Please add more details to question

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for watching, i have updated my question. And I haven't used logstash before, does it fit for those scenarios as I describe?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - use the [Kafka Connect Elasticsearch connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-elasticsearch/docs/elasticsearch_connector.html). This will make your life a LOT easier. The Kafka Connect API is specifically designed to do all of this hard stuff for you (restarts, offset management, etc). As an end-user you just need to set up a configuration file. You can read an example of using Kafka Connect [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-1/).

Kafka Connect is part of Apache Kafka. The Elasticsearch connector is open source and available on its own on [github](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch). Alternatively, just download [Confluent Platform](https://www.confluent.io/download/) which bundles the latest version of Kafka with connectors (including Elasticsearch, HDFS, etc) and a bunch of other useful tools.

Comment: Do you have any idea to get the data importing progress and error logs if using kafka connect elasticsearch ?